# Create ViewController using nib in ViewDidLoad return nil

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a Container ViewController A and a Child ViewController B
In the ViewController A's viewDidLoad I init ViewControler B from nib and add it as a child of Viewcontroller A but the ViewControler B always nil.

Here is my code.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
       self.currentViewController = 
            ViewControlerB(nibName: "ViewControllerB", bundle: nil)
       self.currentViewController!.view
           .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       self.addChildViewController(self.currentViewController!)
       self.addSubView(self.currentViewController!.view, 
                       toParentView: viewContainer)
      super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

My self.currentViewController always be nil and cause crash. Can anyone explain to me why is that?

Plasese help ^^'

Comment: `super.viewDidLoad()` should be first statement of viewDidload!!!

Comment: already did that but nothing change. ^^

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't answer actually!!! It was just suggesion

Comment: Is `init(nibName:bundle:)` a failable initializer? Then you may have misspelled the nib name (`ViewControlerB` vs `ViewControllerB`).

Comment: No my friend. I check the nib name. There is no misspelled. The ViewControllerB is just an example name to describe my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that you check these two answers :

1- Check nib name.

2- Change bundle from nil to (NSBundle.mainBundle()).

Comment: I check both of your recommendation but nothing change. Thanks Abd Aboudi